# elementaryos slow boot

Tags: release-juno, boot, grub

slow boot elementaryos juno I still haven't solved this problem, I read earlier responses to this slow boot question but none helped.please help

systemd-analyze critical-chain picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxcVO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do you require Juno? You could try updating/upgrading to Jolnir.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing your /etc/systemd/system.conf file?

```
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system.conf
```

Uncomment the **#DefaultTimeoutStartSec** line and set it to 5 seconds:

```
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=5s
```

Then save the file, reboot and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks i did but still the issue exist

Answer (score 0):

Please provide output of:

1) `systemd-analyze time`

2) `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20`

3) `sudo blkid`

4) Content of file **/etc/fstab**